# Use of undeclared identificer 'CCTextureCache'

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d v3 and trying to customize my Particle Effects with an image, with this code:

```
CCParticleSystem *particleSystem = [[CCParticleGalaxy alloc] initWithTotalParticles:20];
    particleSystem.texture = [[CCTextureAtlas sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"star.png"];
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Use of undeclared identificer 'CCTextureCache'
```

Where is this class, so I can reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCTextureCache` is going to be removed in future Cocos2D releases, so its header has been removed from `cocos2d.h` and is not imported anymore by default.

In future you should use:

```
[CCTexture textureWithFile:@"star.png"]
```

to create a texture. That method will automatically handle caching for you.